# How to add CardView in RecyclerView Dynamically in Android???

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

> I am working on a application where I have to add *cardView* to
>   *recyclerView* *dynamically*, but it is not working.
>
> This is my code :-

```
Button okBTN;
     EditText enterCornerNumberET;
     private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
     private CornerListAdapter mAdapter;
 public int cornervalue;


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.corner_list);


  okBTN = (Button)findViewById(R.id.okBTN);

        enterCornerNumberET = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.enterCornerNumberET);

 mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);


 mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);


 okBTN.setOnClickListener(this);


  @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()){

 case R.id.okBTN:

                cornervalue = Integer.valueOf(enterCornerNumberET.getText().toString().trim());

                Toast.makeText(CornerListActivity.this, ""+cornervalue, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                createCornerList(cornervalue);

               /*if(enterCornerNumberET.getText().toString().trim()==null){


                    Toast.makeText(CornerListActivity.this, "Please enter corner number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }else{

                    createCornerList(cornervalue);

                }*/


                break;

}
}

 private void createCornerList(int cornervalue) {


        for (int i = 0; i < cornervalue; i++) {

            mAdapter=new CornerListAdapter(this,roofCornerArrayList);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        }
    }
```

> Please have a look and let me know what mistake I am doing here. Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here in my code I have set CardView in RecyclerView and For Layout in RecyclerView, I have use StaggeredGridLayoutManager.

dataModel.java (Model Class)

```
private String first;

public String getFirst() {
    return first;
}
 public void setFirst(String first) {
    this.first = first;
}
  public dataModel()
  {}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

RecyclerView recyclerView;
List<dataModel> list;
AdapterViewHolder adapterViewHolder;
dataModel[] dataModels;
String[] first = {"QUICK CAULIFLOWER TABBOULESH",
        "GRILLED CORN WITH MISO BUTTER"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recylcerView);
    int length=first.length;
    dataModels = new dataModel[length];
    list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        dataModels[i] = new dataModel();
        dataModels[i].setFirst(first[i]);
        dataModels[i].setDescription(second[i]);
        dataModels[i].setImage(image[i]);
        list.add(dataModels[i]);
    }
    adapterViewHolder = new AdapterViewHolder(list, MainActivity.this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2,StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterViewHolder);
}
}
```

AdapterViewHolder.java

```
public class AdapterViewHolder extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

private List<dataModel> list;
private Context context;

public AdapterViewHolder(List<dataModel> list, Context context) {
    this.list = list;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout, parent, false); //inflate layout in view
    return new ViewHolder(view);  //return holder
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ((ViewHolder) holder).textViewFirst.setText(list.get(position).getFirst());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView textViewFirst;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textViewFirst=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewFirst);
    }
}
}
```

Here In my code, I have set array of String variable in CardView and after CardView is set in RecyclerView. For set CardView in RecyclerView I have use one AdapterViewHolder. AdapterViewHolder Class extends RecyclerView.Adapter and layout.xml contains cardView with one textView in it. In AdapterViewHolder,In onCreateViewHolder(), I have inflate layout.xml file and in onBindViewHolder() method bind values of dataModel class in textView. At last, In MainActivity.java I have set AdapterViewHolder in RecyclerView.

Answer (score -1):

You can check [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/) for how to use RecyclerView. After any change in data, you can call Adapter's notifyDataSetChanged() to refresh the view.

Comment: Buddy I know how to use recyclerView. Please pay attention and see carefully what I am asking here.

Comment: Did you tried adding `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged` after `mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);`

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < cornervalue; i++) {
 
            mAdapter=new CornerListAdapter(this,roofCornerArrayList);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        } `

You are creating Adapter and setting it to recyclerView inside loop. It's wrong thing to do first of all. Never ever initialise objects inside loop. Btw what does `roofCornerArrayList` has? Does it even has some data cause if it's null or blank, then returning the size from `getItemCount` method will return 0 or thrown nullPointerException.

Comment: roofCornerArrayList is an object of Bean class which I was using previously when user used to add corner details one by one.. but now they want it to create UI first and according to the count

Comment: Your adapter should take care of the number of items that needs to be displayed along with the UI that needs to be displayed for each item. You can pass the count or model object to adapter and return the layout that needs to be shown. If your object count returns 0 form adapter nothing will be shown.